# Sphinx Geodist search acting strange

Tags: php, sphinx, geo

I've been having some issues with my Sphinx geodist search recently, and I'm lost as to what the problem might be.

Sphinx conf:

```
index vacancy
{
    source          = vacancies
    path            = C:\workspace\tmp\sphinx\data\vacancies
    docinfo         = extern
    charset_type    = utf-8
}

source vacancies : base
{
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT radians(Latitude) as latitude, radians(Longitude) as longitude \
        FROM vacancies as v

    sql_attr_float  = latitude
    sql_attr_float  = longitude
}
```

I've snipped out some irrelevant information from the index query for clarity.

Here is the PHP I'm running:

```
public function geospatial($lat, $long, $distance, $unit = 'miles')
{
    switch(strtolower($unit)) {
        case 'km':
        case 'kilometers':
            $multiplier = 1000;
        break;
        case 'm':
        case 'miles':
        default:
            $multiplier = 1609.3440;
        break;
    }

    $radius = (float) ($distance * $multiplier);
    $this->Client->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
    $this->Client->SetGeoAnchor('latitude', 'longitude', (float) deg2rad($lat), (float) deg2rad($long));
    $this->Client->SetFilterFloatRange('@geodist', 0.0, $radius);
    $this->Client->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@geodist ASC");

    return $this->Client->query('', 'vacancy');
}
```

I'm getting odd results. For example, I set distance (miles) to be 50 and I receive results that are 400+ miles away. Therefore, the query does do *something*, but not what it should do.

I've had a gander at multiple "tutorials" such as:

http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/05/02/geo-distance-search-in-sphinx/

http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2011/06/17/an-introduction-to-distance-based-searching-in-sphinx/

and

http://www.god-object.com/2009/10/20/geospatial-search-using-sphinx-search-and-php/

and nothing seems out of place.

I know that my dataset is correct in terms of latitude/ longitude points, so I believe it's some issue with my config, or some errant PHP. I'd like to add that this was indeed working at some point (honest!), so it's likely an issue with maintenance/ extensibility.

I understand that questions of this type are a pain to debug, so I'm not looking for a solid answer anymore than just a hint at what could be out of place.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the attributes in the resultset? Do the @geodist values look sane?

Comment: Hmm just had another check (testing with 100 mile radius) and my geodist attribute is set to 5. The two results I do get back have a geodist below 5, but one is over 400 miles away when I plot to a map. I'm also missing other results I expect that are truly within 100 miles. I'm not sure where to begin looking for the culprit here.

Comment: What does "my geodist attribute is set to 5" mean? If its set to 5, how are you getting below 5 in the results?

Comment: Turns out one of the joins on my query was incorrect. Ironically I removed this from the question as I wanted to keep it concise. Thanks for your quick responses, all sorted now. I'll go sit in a corner.

Comment: At least figured it out!